# What is '| = ' in python?

Tags: python

I am unable to understand the `|=` part. 
Here is a [link](https://github.com/coala-analyzer/coala/compare/sils/resf#diff-de9fc101e1c104b6a2d71ff3543c7087R25) to the code where this operator is used.

```
affected_files |= set(modified_file_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: This looks like a combination of an OR operation and an assigment operation. I.e. (1) Binary OR the value of _affected\_files_ with the result of _set(modified\_file\_dict.keys())_. (2) Assign the result to _affected\_files_

Comment: "|=" is the C/C++ OR EQUALS, x = x | y is the same as x |= y

Comment: @rresol did any of the answers help?

Comment: yup! @ReutSharabani's  was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [set update](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) as explained in the docs:

> `s.update(t)` update `s |= t` -- return set s with elements added from t

Comment: Thanks @ReutSharabani

Answer (score 1):

What you end up doing is to create the union of the sets `a` and `b`.

However it needs to be pointed out that there is a delicate difference between

```
a = a | b
```

and

```
a |= b
```

The first line is calling `a.__or__`, the second line is calling `a.__ior__`.

`__or__` will return a new set. `__ior__` will *update* `a` in place with the elements from `b`. Consider the following example, where the custom class adds some print statements to the methods involved:

```
>>> class MySet(set):
...     def __or__(self, other):
...         print('calling __or__')
...         return super(MySet, self).__or__(other)
...     def __ior__(self, other):
...         print('calling __ior__')
...         return super(MySet, self).__ior__(other)
... 
>>> a = MySet({1,2})
>>> b = {3}
>>> c = a
>>> 
>>> a = a | b # build new set from the union of a and b, reassign name a
calling __or__
>>> a
{1, 2, 3}
>>> c
MySet({1, 2})
```

In this example, `c` is still the set `{1,2}`.

```
>>> a = MySet({1,2})
>>> b = {3}
>>> c = a
>>> 
>>> a |= b # update a
calling __ior__
>>> a
MySet({1, 2, 3})
>>> c
MySet({1, 2, 3})
```

In this example, `c` has been mutated as well, because `a` and `c` never stopped to be names for the same set.

So the thing to keep in mind when you do `a |= b` is that the change will be seen across *all* names for the set with the name `a`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) `|`, which means `OR`.

Thus, when you do `a |= blah`, it's doing `a = a | blah`.

```
>>> a = False
>>> a |= True
>>> a
True
```

In your case, when you use it with sets, it's getting the union of two sets (i.e, what is in one set OR another).

Thus, with `affected_files |= set(modified_file_dict.keys())`, `affected_files` will contain items from both sets.

Comment: He is referring to this line in his link: `affected_files |= set(modified_file_dict.keys())`

Comment: @ReutSharabani The same logic is applied. `affected_files` contains what is in `affected_files` OR the set

Comment: It may be the same logic for consistency and least astonishment, but it's not the bitwise operator.

Comment: "Thus, when you do a |= blah, it's doing a = a | blah" <- This is wrong for sets, and some other data types. `a |= blah` is mutating `a` in place. `a = a | blah` is building a new set and reassigns the name `a`.

Comment: The name of the operator *is* "bitwise or", its just that the `__or__` and `__ior__` functions override it for sets.

Answer (score 0):

[Python refernce on bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

The operator | is the OR bitwise operator, so for instance, let's take 2 | 4.

2 = 10 in binary and 4 = 100 in binary. So 2 OR 4 is the bit-by-bit or.

In other words: 010 OR 100 = 110 = 6 in decimal.

So 2 | 4 = 6

If applied to variables, a = a | b is like typing a |= b, that's a shorter typing for the same operation.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: "a = a | b is like typing a |= b" <- This is wrong. There's an example in my answer that explains the difference.

Comment: I only thought about sample variables like integers.

You're right